# Is cpo&vim a special syntax?

Tags: vimscript

In scripts it is customary to do something like:

```
let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

... script ...

let &cpo = s:save_cpo
```

To ensure nocompatible mode for the script.

Is:

```
set cpo&vim
```

some sort of special syntax, as in `foo & bar`? Or is it more like a command, trigger line or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's a special syntax to reset options to the Vim defaults. From [`:help :set-&vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset-%26vim):

```
:se[t] {option}&        Reset option to its default value.  May depend on the
                        current value of 'compatible'. {not in Vi}
:se[t] {option}&vi      Reset option to its Vi default value. {not in Vi}
:se[t] {option}&vim     Reset option to its Vim default value. {not in Vi}

:se[t] all&             Set all options, except terminal options, to their
                        default value.  The values of 'term', 'lines' and
                        'columns' are not changed. {not in Vi}
```

I found it by just typing `:help &vim` (which also goes to `:help :set-&vim`) :-)

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I've been looking at cpo, http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#use-cpo-save etc.

Answer (score 6):

`cpo` means `compatible option` and `&` means option variable, so `&cpo` represents the value of compatible option.

`set cpo&vim` is a special syntax which tells vim to reset the option of `cpo` which defaults to `aABceFs`.

See the doc in [`:h cpo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#cpo)