# Why does vimscript use `set cpo&vim`?

Tags: vimscript

Please explain following two lines found in `synload.vim` file:

```
let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim
```

What is `vim` in the last expression? What is result of such an expression, and what does it affect?

Comment: `What is vim in the last expression?` See `:h set-&vim`

Comment: Yes, exactly! :)

Comment: Note you can find the help page for this with `:h &vim`, which will find the help page Matt mentioned; just FYI for the next time you're confused by something in Vim: just try entering stuff in `:help` and see what comes up :-) Using `:help something<Tab>` to get the autocomplete list is also very useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is cpo&vim a special syntax?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/is-cpovim-a-special-syntax)

Comment: While, I totally agree with you all, the help page doesn't explain why the plugins have this habit.

Comment: l00p, I've edited your question to make it less of a dupe (and more relevant to @LucHermitte 's answer). If you feel the edits go against the grain of the question you were asking, feel free to revert them. But I feel the question stands better on it's own this way

Comment: Fair enough @LucHermitte; I've retracted the duplicate vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It resets [`'cpo'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cpo%27)
 value to its default value.

Some people may be running vim in compatible mode, by choice or not. In those cases, various things would be inhibited, things we usually rely upon when writing plugins -- in particular [`:h line-continuation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#line%2dcontinuation). As a consequence, the plugins would emit many error messages.

Resetting `'cpo'` to its *factory* setting, the plugin becomes resilient to these hostile (IMO) configurations.

This syntax could be used with many (all?) vim options. Before doing that, we record the old value in order to properly restore it afterward

```
let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim
.
. plugin code
.
let &cpo = s:cpo_save
```

Comment: @BLayer Indeed. thanks :)

Comment: No problemo       :) ...